# Pyinstaller not printing any output while building the package

Tags: python, command-line, output, pyinstaller

I'm using pyinstaller v. 5.9.0 to build my Python 3.10 script into an .exe file (using Windows 10):

```
pyinstaller --clean --console -F -i resources\Icon01.ico --add-data resources\;\resources\ -n MyApp.exe Main.py
```

The generated package is working, however while the package is being built I see no output from pyinstaller (it should print some status messages).

This happens either if I run pyinstaller directly from Windows shell (cmd) or from a Terminal window opened in PyCharm; also redirecting the output to a text file produces an empty log.

As I said above, however, the built app, which is bound to console, is working as expected and produces outputs to stdout.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Well if the generated executable works then I would say you are not doing anything wrong.

Comment: True! 
However, if a program is supposed to print some output, it would also be nice to know what's there. _THIS_ program is working for me now, but what if I write another and need to check everything is fine when I'm going to distribute it?